# Sort a list by Code, Then by Name

Tags: c#, sorting, delegates

I have a list of objects.
I sort this list by Code by writing this line:

```
Result.Sort(delegate(Position p1, Position p2) { return p1.Code.CompareTo(p2.Code); });
```

But I want to sort this line first by Code and then by Name.
How to I do this?

Comment: Which .Net framework are you targeting? It's very old "fashion" code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without LINQ:

```
Result.Sort(delegate(Position p1, Position p2) 
            { 
                var byCode = p1.Code.CompareTo(p2.Code); 
                return byCode == 0 ? p1.Name.CompareTo(p2.Name) : byCode; 
            });
```

Or the same logic using comparers:

```
Result.Sort(new PositionComparer());
class PositionComparer : IComparer<Position>
{
    public int Compare(Position p1, Position p2) 
    { 
        var byCode = p1.Code.CompareTo(p2.Code); 
        return byCode == 0 ? p1.Name.CompareTo(p2.Name) : byCode; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Why won't you use LINQ?

```
var ordered = list.OrderBy(x => x.Code).ThenBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: I personally always use LINQ as you mentioned above (because syntax is awesome) but sometimes you can't, for instance my issue is im using Unity3d (Game Engine) and on iOS it doesn't work :( (yet)

Comment: @StephenLautier, since when can iOS run .Net framework code? (maybe I'm out dated... Are you using the Mono project?)

Comment: yes as you said using I'm using Mono. Specifically using Unity3D (GameEngine) which is build on Mono and unfortunately its using an older version of Mono, not the latest.