# sort and group a list of objects by multiple properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have a complicated sort/grouping that needs to be performed with a list of objects.

The objects have three properties:
EventName
Start
End

I'm given the name of an event "EventName" and the start/end times for said event, and populate a List.

Now comes the hard part.

The requirements are:
- the same EventName can have multiple entries with different start/end times
- events are to be sorted by start time, with the earliest occurring first
- events, if they have the same start time, should then be sorted by shortest to longest run times.
- events are then to be grouped, so all events with the same name are listed in ascending order, under the event name.
- Events with different names, but the same overall *earliest* start time are to be sorted alphabetically.

For example:

### List(0):

EventName: Test 2
Start: 10am
End: 3pm

### List(1):

EventName: Test 2
Start: 10am
End: 11am

### List(2):

EventName: Test 1
Start: 12pm
End: 1pm

### List(3):

EventName: Test 2
Start: 2pm
End: 3pm

So when all is said and done, the List needs to be sorted to be:

### List(0):

EventName: Test 2
Start: 10am
End: 11am

### List(1):

EventName: Test 2
Start: 10am
End: 3pm

### List(2):

EventName: Test 2
Start: 2pm
End: 3pm

### List(3):

EventName: Test 1
Start: 12pm
End: 1pm

I'm really not sure how to do this. I have this much which doesn't work:

```
theList.OrderBy(o => o.Start).ThenBy(o => o.End).ThenBy(o => o.EventName);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
To make it easier, assume times are converted in 24-hour time and stored as ints as I can easily do that.

Comment: tried `theList.orderBy(p => p.Start).ThenBy(q => q.End - q.Start).ThenBy(EventName)` ?

Comment: @BeytanKurt: no go. Your suggestion doesn't keep them grouped together by EventName. In my example, List(2), starts later than List(3), but needs to appear before List(3) because other events with the same name start before List(3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have it!

Just had to do some minor tweaks to what I already had.

Here's the code that thus far is working as I need it:

```
theList.GroupBy(o => o.EventName).Select(s => s.OrderBy(a => a.Start).ThenBy(a => a.End)).SelectMany(sm => sm).ToList();
```

Where all the other suggestions were falling down was keeping the EventNames grouped together when sorting by the start times.

_

Answer (score 0):

A solution without Linq:

```
theList.Sort(delegate(Event p1, Event p2)
             {
                   var byStart = p1.Start.CompareTo(p2.Start);
                   var byEnd = p1.End.CompareTo(p2.End);
                   var byEventName = p1.EventName.CompareTo(p2.EventName);
                   return byStart == 0 ? byEnd == 0 ? byEventName : byEnd : byStart;
             });
```

Solution adapted from [Sort a list by Code, Then by Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996685/sort-a-list-by-code-then-by-name). Untested. Especially the return statement might need some manipulation. Replace Event by whatever you're using as your List object.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, the code won't work because the namespace "Position" could not be found. When I do a "resolve" I get several for OpenXML WordProcessing, Math, Presentation, Drawing, and others, none of which seem appropriate. Where should Position be referenced from?

Comment: My bad, it shouldn't be Position, it should be the element that your list is made off.

Comment: `Position` should be the type of `o`, but you haven't provided us with that :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the `Start` and `End` into temporary variables without am and pm then perform the sorting operation on these numbers
Suppose the class name having those three properties is `Event`, then here is the linq statement

```
list.Select(s => new
 {
    EventName = s.EventName,
    Start = s.Start,
    End = s.End,
    // getting number without am/pm and where it is pm adding 12
    NumberStart = s.Start.EndsWith("pm") ?
                    12 + Convert.ToInt32(s.Start.Trim('m').TrimEnd('p')) : 
                         Convert.ToInt32(s.Start.Trim('m').TrimEnd('a')),
    NumberEnd = s.End.EndsWith("pm") ?
                    12 + Convert.ToInt32(s.End.Trim('m').TrimEnd('p')) :
                         Convert.ToInt32(s.End.Trim('m').TrimEnd('a'))
 }).OrderBy(s => s.NumberStart)
   .ThenBy(s => s.NumberEnd - s.NumberStart)
   .ThenBy(s => s.EventName)
   .Select(s => new Event { EventName = s.EventName, Start = s.Start, End = s.End });
```

### Edit

try changing the `OrderBy` sequence to

```
.OrderBy(s => s.EventName)
   .ThenBy(s => s.NumberStart)
   .ThenBy(s => s.NumberEnd - s.NumberStart)
```

Comment: Why are you trimming both a and p if you're already checking whether it ends with pm?

Comment: Thanks for the copde @WaqasRaja. unfortunately, it falls short because it's not keeping the events with the same name together after the sorting. See my example. List(2), starts later than List(3), but needs to appear before List(3) because other events with the same name start before List(3).

Comment: @user3810900 you cannot do this in single statement